# Incrementing a private field in a processing class

Tags: java, arrays, static, field, private-methods

I'm working on this class project in which I have to develop a program that tests whether a user inputted String meets a criteria. For more understanding the source code will be posted at the bottom. Although i made the array "u[]" static, it isnt incremented by the for loop.

**Main Class**

```
package GroupX;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class GbeApp{

  public static void main(String[] args){

      Scanner kb= new Scanner(System.in);
      GbeClass gbebObject= new GbeClass();

      System.out.print("Please enter a password that meets the following criteria:\nat least six characters long\nat least one uppercase and lowercase letter\nand at least one digit\n");

         String temp= kb.nextLine();
         gbeObeject.setPass(temp);//@param String password
         System.out.println(gbebObject.getTest());
  }

}
```

**Gbe Processsing Class**

```
package Groupx;
import java.lang.*;
public class GbeClass{
   public String password;
   private static int u[]= {0,0,0,0};/*here is the issue, the for loop doesnt increment this array */

   public void test(){
      for(int x= 0; x <= password.length()- 1; x++){
          if(Character.isUpperCase(password.charAt(x)))
             u[0]++;
          else if(Character.isLowerCase(password.charAt(x)))
             u[1]++;
          else if(Character.isDigit(password.charAt(x)))
             u[2]++;
          else
             u[3]++;
       }
    }
    public String getTest(){
         if(password.length() <6)
            return "The password must be at least 6 characters or more in length. Please try again";
         if(u[0] <= 0)
            return "The password must contain an uppercase letter. Please try again";
         if(u[1] <= 0)
            return "The password must contain a lowercase letter. Please try again";
         if(u[2] <= 0)
            return "The password must contain a digit.  Please try again";
         else
            return "The password meets the criteria!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `gbeObject.test()`? This code does not compile, please include an actual [mcve].

Comment: In the example you've provided, `password` is never initialized. Do you have an implementation for `setPass()`?